# NetworkX: Add multiple input nodes to a node from a excel cell with comma separated values

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have been using NetworkX library recently. I am trying to add multiple in nodes(predecessors) from an excel column separated by comma.

For the node F10, the predecessors are F07, F09 and F05.

[Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvrwR.png)

[Predecessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncgJ9.png)

I am reading the columns and creating the nodes and edges using *from_pandas_edgelist.*

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, 'Process Step', 'Predecessors',
                         create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

`[('F00', 'F01'), ('F01', 'F02'), ('F02', 'F03'), ('F03', 'F04'), ('F03', 'F06'), ('F03', 'F08'), ('F04', 'F05'), ('F06', 'F07'), ('F08', 'F09'), ('F05,F07,F09', 'F10'), ('F10', 'F11')]`

Reading this way does not create the separate nodes for F10 but they take the input nodes as a single node resulting in this graph.

[Resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJEbN.png)

I want to get the individual connections from the F05, F07, F09 to F10.

Has anyone faced this problem before? I have tried other format of representing the nodes, still it doesnt work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The simplest way to solve your problem is to create another table, in which the predecessor node lists are expanded into separate rows such that you have the standard source column, target column format that networkx expects.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Yes, at the moment I am doing this way. With the JSON input format, the same comma separated representation input works well.  It's not taking it account in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

To create multiple rows from a list of items, you can use the `Pandas` [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method.

However, from the looks of it, the items in the `Predecessor` column aren't formatted like a list to start with, so you first need to convert them to lists.

To do so, you can use the [str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) method, which will separate strings into lists based on a specified delimiter.  In your case, the delimiter is a comma, which will separate `F05,F07,F09` into `['F05', 'F07', 'F09']`.

So for your example, the following should work:

```
df1['Predecessor'] = df1['Predecessor'].str.split(',') # Convert string to list
df1 = df1.explode('Predecessor') # Convert list to separate rows
```

The resulting dataframe looks like this (it isn't clear what's in the first row in the 'Predecessor' column, so it becomes `NaN`):

```
   Process Predecessor
0      F00         NaN
1      F01         F00
2      F02         F01
3      F03         F02
4      F04         F03
5      F05         F04
6      F06         F03
7      F07         F06
8      F08         F03
9      F09         F08
10     F10         F05
10     F10         F07
10     F10         F09
11     F11         F10
```

Now, running `g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, 'Process', 'Predecessor', create_using = nx.DiGraph()` should work the way you expect it to.